# does もの mean thing here?

Tags: interpretation

しかし禰豆子さんのかかっている暗示は人間が家族に見える**もの**では?

Does this mean thing? It feels like the もの substitutes 暗示, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. That is a replacement for 暗示. So the sentence means like *But, the delusion that Nezuko has is **(a delusion)** such that she thinks humans are her family.*

Comment: I'm not sure *delusion* is the right word here.